# Splitting CSV leaves empty line at end of file

Tags: powershell

I have the following code which takes a csv file and splits it based on a column value.

It works but it leaves an empty/new line at the bottom/last line. I've tried tweaking it a few times to remove the empty line with no joy. Would you mind having a look to see what I've missed?

```
$date = Get-Date
$date = $date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
$src = $PSScriptRoot + "\file_export.csv" 
$dstDir = $PSScriptRoot + ".\files_$date"
New-Item -itemType Directory -Force -Path $dstDir

# Delete previous output files
Remove-Item -Path "$dstDir\*"

# Setup for input data via StreamReader
$inData = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList $src

# Initialize the current file name
$currentFile = ""

while ($line = $inData.ReadLine())
{
    $newFile = "$(($line -split ",")[13])_$date.csv"
    if ($newFile -ne $currentFile)
    {
        # We're starting on a new file
        if ($currentFile -ne "")
        {
            # Write out contents of current file
            $outData.ToString() | Out-File -FilePath $dstDir\$currentFile -Encoding ascii
        }
        # Get ready for a new current file
        $currentFile = $newFile
        $outData = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.StringBuilder
        #[void]$outData.Append($header)
    }

    Write-Verbose "$currentFile, $line"
    [void]$outData.AppendLine($line)

} # end main while loop - done reading input
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you can't use cmdlets like `Import-Csv`? This could be as simple as `Import Csv file_export.csv | group Date | foreach { $_.Group | Export-Csv ($_.Name + '.csv')}` at its core.

Comment: Hi, the CSV file has no headers and using the module fails.

Comment: You're aware of the `-Headers` parameter to `Import-Csv`?

Answer (score 0):

you could try to only parse and output `$line` which is not null or empty like:

```
while ($line = $inData.ReadLine())
{
    if(-not ([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($line))) {
        $newFile = "$(($line -split ",")[13])_$date.csv"

        ...

        Write-Verbose "$currentFile, $line"
        [void]$outData.AppendLine($line)
    } # end if string is null or empty
} # end main while loop - done reading input
```

Comment: That errors with the following                                                                  
    At C:\script.ps1:21 char:46
+     if( -not ([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($line)))
+                                              ~
Missing statement block after if ( condition ).
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingStatementBlock

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help, the below code resolves the issue

```
$outData.ToString() | Out-File -FilePath $dstDir\$currentFile -Encoding ascii -NoNewLine
```